# Ajax success function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I have the following Ajax request which I make. Currently if the json response is `true` then the success callback runs. But if the json response is `false` then the success callback isn't run, even if the Ajax request itself is successfully made.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        action: 'check_username',
        user: user_email
    },
    success: function(json) {
        if (json.user_exists == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    action: 'auto_login',
                    user: user_email
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#aux_lightbox_overlay').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
        if (json.user_exists == false) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    action: 'auto_register',
                    user: user_email
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#aux_lightbox_overlay').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So my question is, how do I get the callback to run even if the response is `false`?

Thanks

Comment: this looks server side / php side problem.

Comment: Consider cascading

 `.fail( function(data){
 // code to debug -( may be console.log or alert )
}
);`

to success function to know if the request fails

Comment: this function is communicating with back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `complete` instead `success` and `error`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        action: 'check_username',
        user: user_email
    },
    complete: function(json) {
        if (json.user_exists == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    action: 'auto_login',
                    user: user_email
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#aux_lightbox_overlay').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
        if (json.user_exists == false) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://testdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    action: 'auto_register',
                    user: user_email
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#aux_lightbox_overlay').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when the user does not exist, `json.user_exists` is indeed equal to `false`? If I understand you correctly, the `if (json.user_exists == false){...}` statement is not triggered, so there is something weird there.

For more robust code, you could change

```
if (json.user_exists == true) {
  // ...
}
if (json.user_exists == false){
  // ...
}
```

into

```
if (json.user_exists == true) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```